# using C# GUI app to query a MySQL database with an online provider

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, wcf

Hosting services commonly provide support for webapps (say ASP.net, Rails or Django) and a few databases (e.g. SQLServer, MySQL). 
I prefer C# WinForms for most of my own apps (speed of graphics updates eg.), but I'd like to have a webbased DB behind it so I can access it from multiple locations.

Is there a reason that I couldn't use such a web-provider just for my databases, i.e. not serve a dynamic webpage but just answer my sql queries?

Existing posts that appear to answer similar questions exist, but I would like to obtain more clarity.
E.g. does the webserver provide additional security that is otherwise hard to obtain?

Does the 'correct' answer include the keyword WCF? Do I need the hosting service to support WCF explicitly?

Comment: I would think as long as the connection string is correct, you could access a web-based DB from any platform - web app, WinForm, etc.  WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) is a replacement for .NET Remoting and legacy ASMX web services - you could look into WCF Data Services.  There is no "correct" answer per se - the key is being able to gain a connection to the DB server.  There are several front-end approaches, and a number of ways to access the DB - ADO.NET, Entity Framework to name two.

Comment: Also, you could use the MySQL equivalent of MS Sql Server Management Studios to connect.

Comment: The WCF approach would require you to write a service (either a regular WCF service or a WCF data service) that would have to be hosted somewhere to connect to the database in addition to your front-end app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical limitation in accomplishing what you are asking, but most of the hosting providers (shared hosting mainly) restrict access to their database to be within their internal network. If you can find a hosting provider who provides you the option to connect from external network you are good to go.

One thing you want to keep in mind when you are distributing your `winforms` client is that the connection string can be extracted by the end user if he is a smart enough person. It would be prudent to encrypt the connection string in the configuration file and also use encryption for the connection it is making to the database (`SslMode=Required` in the connection string).

When you are using WCF, it helps you to implement an additional layer of abstraction and protection. You can use your own membership to authenticate the user who can have access to the WCF services and not worry about connecting from the client to the database directly.

All being considered, going with a WCF or any other web service layer instead of directly connecting to the database from the client would be better approach.